# fabric.js limit rotation to x degrees with rotation handle

Tags: javascript, rotation, limit, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js and trying to allow rotation for any object on my canvas, not freely 360 degrees, but only 15 degrees at a time, using the rotation handle. I searched really hard but couldn't find an answer so far. Is this possible?

Comment: You might be able to edit [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jsbqd36/1/) (got it from [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230348/rotation-and-scaling-controls-are-off-after-using-setangle-in-fabric-js)) to fit your needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shorter solution:

```
canvas.on('object:rotating', function(options) {
  var step = 15;
  options.target.angle = Math.round(options.target.angle / step) * step;
});
```

**UPD:** since 1.6.7 you can just use `fabric.Object.snapAngle` property:

```
someFabricObject.snapAngle = 15;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `canvas.on("object:rotating")` to interfer with rotation of all objects.
I defined a set of valid angles, and then on the rotation event i checked which one to use.

```
var angles = [0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 195, 210, 225, 240, 255, 270, 285, 300, 315, 330, 345, 360];

canvas.on("object:rotating", function(rotEvtData) {
    var targetObj = rotEvtData.target;
    var angle = targetObj.angle % 360;
    for (var i=0; i < angles.length; i++) {
       if (angle <=  angles[i]) {
          targetObj.angle = angles[i];
          break;
       }
    }
  });
```

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    fill: 'red',
    width: 90,
    height: 90
});

canvas.add(rect);

var angles = [0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 195, 210, 225, 240, 255, 270, 285, 300, 315, 330, 345, 360];
canvas.on("object:rotating", function(rotEvtData) {
    var targetObj = rotEvtData.target;
    var angle = targetObj.angle % 360;
    for (var i=0; i < angles.length; i++) {
       if (angle <=  angles[i]) {
          targetObj.angle = angles[i];
          break;
       }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's very elegant!