# fabricjs - snap to grid scaling for angled objects

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

So I have the snap to grid function below. It works fine when the object has 0 angle, but does not snap to grid properly once it's angled (only for left and top sides). This is because it is now taking into account both left and top attributes rather than just left or top respectively.

The solution I'm thinking is using triangular maths (pythagoras) but am unsure of how to get the current left/top attributes since `target.left` and `target.top` holds the data for the currently scaled object.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
   selection: false
});
var grid = 50;

// create grid
for (var i = 0; i < (600 / grid); i++) {
   canvas.add(new fabric.Line([i * grid, 0, i * grid, 600], {
      stroke: '#ccc',
      selectable: false
   }));
   canvas.add(new fabric.Line([0, i * grid, 600, i * grid], {
      stroke: '#ccc',
      selectable: false
   }))
}

// add objects
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
   left: 100,
   top: 100,
   strokeWidth: 0,
   width: 50,
   height: 50,
   fill: '#faa',
   originX: 'left',
   angle: 50,
   originY: 'top',
   centeredRotation: true
}));

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
   left: 300,
   top: 300,
   radius: 50,
   fill: '#9f9',
   originX: 'left',
   originY: 'top',
   strokeWidth: 0,
   centeredRotation: true
}));

// snap to grid
canvas.on('object:moving', options => {
   options.target.set({
      left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
      top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
   });
});

canvas.on('object:scaling', options => {
 

          var target = options.target;
          let grid = 50;


          var w = target.getWidth(),
            h = target.getHeight(),
            snap = {  // Closest snapping points
               top: Math.round(target.top / grid) * grid,
               left: Math.round(target.left / grid) * grid,
               bottom: Math.round((target.top + h) / grid) * grid,
               right: Math.round((target.left + w) / grid) * grid
            },
            threshold = grid, // add a multiplier to change closeness e.g. * 2
            dist = {  // Distance from snapping points
               top: Math.abs(snap.top - target.top),
               left: Math.abs(snap.left - target.left),
               bottom: Math.abs(snap.bottom - target.top - h),
               right: Math.abs(snap.right - target.left - w)
            },
            attrs = {
               scaleX: target.scaleX,
               scaleY: target.scaleY,
               top: target.top,
               left: target.left
            };
          switch (target.__corner) {
            case 'tl':
               if (dist.left < dist.top && dist.left < threshold) {
                  attrs.scaleX = (w - (snap.left - target.left)) / target.width;
                  attrs.scaleY = (attrs.scaleX / target.scaleX) * target.scaleY;
                  attrs.top = target.top + (h - target.height * attrs.scaleY);
                  attrs.left = snap.left;
               } else if (dist.top < threshold) {
                  attrs.scaleY = (h - (snap.top)) / target.height;
                  attrs.scaleX = (attrs.scaleY / target.scaleY) * target.scaleX;
                  attrs.left += (w - target.width * attrs.scaleX);
                  attrs.top = snap.top;
               }
               break;
            case 'mt':
               if (dist.top < threshold) {
                  console.log("scaling");
                  attrs.scaleY = (h - (snap.top - target.top)) / target.height;
                  attrs.top = snap.top;
               }
               break;
            case 'tr':
               if (dist.right < dist.top && dist.right < threshold) {
                  attrs.scaleX = (snap.right - target.left) / target.width;
                  attrs.scaleY = (attrs.scaleX / target.scaleX) * target.scaleY;
                  attrs.top = target.top + (h - target.height * attrs.scaleY);
               } else if (dist.top < threshold) {
                  attrs.scaleY = (h - (snap.top - target.top)) / target.height;
                  attrs.scaleX = (attrs.scaleY / target.scaleY) * target.scaleX;
                  attrs.top = snap.top;
               }
               break;
            case 'ml':
               if (dist.left < threshold) {
                  attrs.scaleX = (w - (snap.left - target.left)) / target.width;
                  attrs.left = snap.left;
               }
               break;
            case 'mr':
               if (dist.right < threshold) attrs.scaleX = (snap.right - target.left) / target.width;
               break;
            case 'bl':
               if (dist.left < dist.bottom && dist.left < threshold) {
                  attrs.scaleX = (w - (snap.left - target.left)) / target.width;
                  attrs.scaleY = (attrs.scaleX / target.scaleX) * target.scaleY;
                  attrs.left = snap.left;
               } else if (dist.bottom < threshold) {
                  attrs.scaleY = (snap.bottom - target.top) / target.height;
                  attrs.scaleX = (attrs.scaleY / target.scaleY) * target.scaleX;
                  attrs.left += (w - target.width * attrs.scaleX);
               }
               break;
            case 'mb':
               if (dist.bottom < threshold) attrs.scaleY = (snap.bottom - target.top) / target.height;
               break;
            case 'br':
               if (dist.right < dist.bottom && dist.right < threshold) {
                  attrs.scaleX = (snap.right - target.left) / target.width;
                  attrs.scaleY = (attrs.scaleX / target.scaleX) * target.scaleY;
               } else if (dist.bottom < threshold) {
                  attrs.scaleY = (snap.bottom - target.top) / target.height;
                  attrs.scaleX = (attrs.scaleY / target.scaleY) * target.scaleX;
               }
               break;
            default:
              break;
          }
          target.set(attrs);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: It isn't really clear what you are trying to achieve. I see snapping occurs when the rectangle is angled. Top left corner of rectangle is snapped to top left corner of grid. How do you want snapping when angled?

Comment: @marekful I've updated the snippet so that the square is angled at the start. Try to pull the left side and you'll see it move and scale without snapping.

Comment: I don't get this. I can resize the rectangle by pulling any of its four sides. Resizing is snapped and no moving occurs during resize. You code works for me quite well :)

Comment: @marekful I must've forgotten to save it. Try again now.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise at first that corner resize was buggy and only tried sides which were fine. Scale is calculated based on the snap and event coordinates using arithmetic operations which is fine when angle is zero but when it's not, you need trigonometric functions to get the distance.

Comment: @marekful yeah, but I'm just not sure how to get the correct left/top points. I'm thinking of using scale the calculate the necessary relativeness of the left/top then using the angle to decide whether the left should be going to the left or right

Comment: I never used Fabric before yesterday, sorry :) Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230348/rotation-and-scaling-controls-are-off-after-using-setangle-in-fabric-js) though. Using `target.setAngle(lastAngle).setCoords();` instead of `target.set(attrs);` corrects the angled resize but breaks snapping in this example, however you can make snapping work based on this other SO Q/A. (lastAngle is set in object:modified eventhandler.)